# Python Scraping fb comments from a website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape facebook comments using Beautiful Soup on the below website pages.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

url = 'http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/15/facebook-lightbox/'

fd = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(fd)

fb_comment = soup("div", {"class":"postText"}).find(text=True)

print fb_comment
```

The output is a null set. However, I can clearly see the facebook comment is within those above tags in the inspect element of the techcrunch site (I am little new to Python and was wondering if the approach is correct and where I am going wrong?)

Comment: Those elements are most likely generated with JavaScript and aren't in the HTML.

Comment: I agree with Blender. You won't see them without running the JavaScript. Also, you need to call a read on `fd`.

Comment: Thanks Blender and Justin Peel.

Answer (score 1):

Like Christopher and Thiefmaster: it is all because of javascript.

But, if you really need that information, you can still retrieve it thanks to Selenium on http://seleniumhq.org then use beautifulsoup on this output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Selenium, I'm using Selenium and trying to feed the output of Selenium as the input to BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook comments are loaded dynamically using AJAX. You *can* scrape the original page to retrieve this:

```
<fb:comments href="http://techcrunch.com/2012/05/15/facebook-lightbox/" num_posts="25" width="630"></fb:comments>
```

After that you need to send a request to some Facebook API that will give you the comments for the URL in that tag.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just wanted to say that I used the following API (without the need to run any JavaScript as facebook has a very friendly API that fetches messages directly) http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id='URL'&limit=500&fields=message. This returns the id, message, and  time stamp directly.

Comment: Please consider posting this as an answer and then accepting it. Since you tagged the question with python consider sharing some code in case it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the page you are looking for are not included in the source file. Use a browser and you can see this for yourself by opening the page source.

You will need to use something like [pywebkitgtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/) to have the javascript executed before passing the document to BeautifulSoup

Comment: That sounds like major overkill. He can just access whatever API the Facebook JavaScript usually accesses. No need to *run* any JavaScript.