# Jsoup getting information from span class

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to get this information with Jsoup:
[image]

I need to get the word kisaltilmis and here is what I have tried so far:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://translate.google.bg/?hl=bg#en/tr/abbreviated")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .get();

Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#result_box > span");

for(Element e : newsHeadlines){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the content is not generated via ajax after the call? if you print out the doc, do you see the element?

Comment: Yes actually, It is generated via ajax because when I print the whole doc it does not print the element i want ://

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414876/python-scraping-fb-comments-from-a-website this is a similair problem. http://www.kochi-coders.com/2014/05/06/scraping-a-javascript-enabled-web-page-using-beautiful-soup-and-phantomjs/ something like this might help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation that you are trying to get is generated via AJAX call. So this information could not be found in the page source.

The actual query goes to `https://translate.google.bg/translate_a/single`. It returns a file that looks like the following

```
[[["kısaltılmış","abbreviated",,,0],...
```

Unfortunately, it is not a valid JSON file, due to missing values between commas, so the information should be extracted manually.

Here is the code snippet that loads the information from server

```
System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
final String query = "abbreviated";
final String urlPrefix = "https://translate.google.bg/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=en&tl=tr&hl=bg&dt=at&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qca&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&source=bh&ssel=0&tsel=0&kc=1&tk=811697.665342&q=";
try (final InputStream stream = new URL(urlPrefix +  URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8")).openStream()) {
    final String line = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Notice, that Google charges money for the usage of Google Translate API, so, if you will try to get the translation too often, you, probably, will be banned.

Comment: Replace the `,,` with a space and you'll have a valid JSON.

Comment: @TGD As this API is not documented, we could run into other issues, e.g. escaping rules. And anyway, preprocessing is a kind of "manual extraction".